# How to get Fame and Prestige Points

Tags: pathfinder-1e, campaign-settings

I have read the pathfinder society field guide and want to use the *Prestige and Fame System* but I still have a few questions about how it works.

They write a lot about what to do with it but not how to get them (or maybe I missed it). So e.g. if you have 40 Fame and 1 PP you are a Capitain in the Andoran fraction and you can buy stuff for 31000 gp. As well as you can spend your 1 PP for several things.

Somewhere (I cannot remember where) I have read that the members get these points for accomplished missions what is quite obvious but I need help how many points the get for what kind of missions and on what levels. I do not want to end up with an unbalanced system. So I guess a high level character gets more points for a mission than a low level character. Anyone who can help me out here?

Answer (score 3):

The [Reputation and Fame](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/reputation-and-fame) mechanics, as written, expect a character to gain about 4-6 prestige points per character level, capped by your Fame score. Each time you gain a fame point, you also gain one prestige point. Those are earned by completing objectives that will help your reputation with a specific group or region.

> **Prestige Points**
>
> Prestige Points represent your ability to leverage your Fame. **You earn Prestige Points (PP) by completing objectives during the course of play**. The GM decides which deeds, goals, or story elements are most important and awards players for completing them accordingly. Each time your Fame increases, you also gain 1 Prestige Point. **In a typical campaign, you should gain approximately 4 to 6 Prestige Points per character level**. Your current Prestige Points can never exceed your Fame. You can’t share Prestige Points with other characters; only the character who earned them can spend them. Most of the time, you spend points on rewards—titles, temporary abilities, or bonuses on tasks associated with your interests.

The table of **Fame Events** are examples of what situations would increase your Fame (and award a prestige point), like **gaining a level** (+1). The GM is free to adjust and create new rewards as necessary.

The book ([ultimate campaign](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8x64?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Campaign)) explains how this should be awarded and gives us some examples of what is to be expected for certain amount of prestige points. The various published guilds and schools have additional options that can be awarded to their members.

For example, the [Inner Sea Magic](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8mfs?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Inner-Sea-Magic) presents four schools of magic: Kintargo Opera House (Cheliax), Oenopion Fleshforges (Nex), Poisoner’s Guild (River Kingdoms) and White Grotto (Absalom).

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in the Pathfinder Society shared campaign documentation [online](http://paizo.com/products/btpy84k4?Pathfinder-Society-Roleplaying-Guild-Guide), a scenario (which awards XP for one third of a level) can award 0-2 prestige points, depending on success. There is an expectation that not all goals will be met. A module (which generally gives enough XP for one level) awards 4 Prestige Points.

Comment: Note that the Pathfinder Society [Field Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8mfq?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Pathfinder-Society-Field-Guide) is not the same thing as the Pathfinder Society [Guild Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy84k4). The systems are similar in concept, but completely different in execution.

Comment: Of course, but the information is about the same in-game organisation, so potentially still applies.